# Toggle jQuery Overlap

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a button script from jQuery (source:https://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox).

I have run in to an issue when I am using .toggle

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Button - Checkboxes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"     href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <style>
  #format { margin-top: 2em; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="format">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1"><label for="check1">Option 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2"><label for="check2">Option 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check3"><label for="check3">Option 3</label>
    <p id="text1">1</p>
<p id="text2">2</p>
<p id="text3">3</p>
<p id="text4">4</p>
<p id="text5">5</p>
<p id="text6">6</p>
<p id="text7">7</p>
<p id="text8">8</p>
<p id="text9">9</p>
<p id="text10">10</p>
<p id="text11">11</p>      
<script>
$(function() {
      $( "#check" ).button();
      $( "#format" ).buttonset();
  });
  $( "#check2" ).click(function() {
      $( "#text2, #text3, #text6, #text7, #text8, #text9" ).toggle(display);

  });$( "#check3" ).click(function() {
      $( "#text2, #text3, #text5, #text6, #text7, #text8, #text9, #text10, #text11" ).toggle();
  });
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see some of the things I want toggled appear 2 times.

I want to be able to check and uncheck the buttons at will so using .hide instead did not work as they would not reappear on a second click.

if both are selected I want a field that appears twice to hide.

Anyone have asolution for this?

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: Don't know how to use this, however I have updated the code above.

Comment: are you trying something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ajj2b5y8/?

Comment: Yes, so as you can see, if you only select option 2 you are left with 5 answers and when you only select option 3 you have 2 answers, but when you select both you get seven.
I am wanting it so that only common numbers will show.
So for example if option 1 and option 2 are selected, then only answers 1 and four appear.

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/ajj2b5y8/1/? please let me know if this works for u.

Comment: No because I need it to be so that when option 2 is selected _alone_ it will show 1, 4, 5, 10 and 11 and only when option 3 is selected ir will hide the 5 10 and 11